# PS3 through line in?

Tags: linux, audio, ps3, voice-chat

I'm looking for a way to chat through LAN (via PC) while playing PS3.  Would it be possible to run my PS3's sound through my desktop's "line in" and somehow (if possible) mixing it with my normal PC sound to produce one output that I could, say, use with headphones?

I'll add that I'm currently running to line in (not mic) from the line out on my monitor (Flatron W2453V), where my PS3 is hooked up via HDMI. I tried running femalex2 to male 3.5mm splitter, but it dims my PC sound when PS3 sound is available. Chat would be impossible.

Currently running Linux Mint if that's of any concern, but am willing to switch to any flavour of Linux to get this working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably be best off mixing it at the output stage.  Get a little mixing module (available from radio shack and the like) and connect both the PS3 and the PC's sound out to it, then connect your headphones to that.  You can then easily set the different levels for PC & PS3 sound without faffing with software settings.

Comment: Nevermind! Found a few on Amazon. :)